# Show my iOS app in text Copy and Share option like notes app

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, uipasteboard

I was looking for a solution to show my iOS app in plain text **copy and share**(Pasteboard) list. UIPasteboard is working fine, the only challenge is to open app from the UIPasteboard share option. I set **supported document types** for plain text, still my app is not visible. Any thought/suggestion.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve this issue through Share Extension, earlier I was following the Pasteboard approach, it was not the correct way. To enable Text share extension we have to enable **NSExtensionActivationRule** *NSExtensionActivationSupportsText* for text share like Image/other files share extension we have to handle text content inside NSItemProvider.